# Load data frame from struct

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm learning polars rust version and I have a question: is there a way to create a dataframe (or lazy dataframe) by using a struct?

I have some financial data from a data provider that send me a json through http request.

I deserialise this json into a struct and I'd like to create a polars data frame with this struct.

Alternative, is there an analog of python polars.read_json in rust version?

Comment: What does this struct look like?

Comment: Found this solution recently after running into the same issue, here is the link to the question I posted. Please note you must have the json feature enabled in your cargo.toml file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167416/creating-polars-dataframe-from-vecstruct

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming after `read_json` your dataframe is looking like the below example and trying to answer accordingly.

```
import polars as pl
exp = {

"a": ["a", "aa","aaa"],
"b": ["b", "bb","bbb"],
"c": ["c", "cc","ccc"]

}
df_exp=pl.DataFrame(exp).select([pl.struct(["a", "b"]).alias("first"),pl.struct(["b", "c"]).alias("second")])
df_exp
```

Result

```
shape: (3, 2)

 first        second
struct[2]    struct[2]
{"a","b"}    {"b","c"}
{"aa","bb"}  {"bb","cc"}
{"aaa","bbb"}{"bbb","ccc"}
```

If you slice one element of the column first  you can see the struct with field names like below.

```
df_exp['first'][0]
```

Result

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

To unnest the dataframe you can use `unnest` function to create columns with respect to field like below.

```
df_exp.unnest('first')
```

Result

```
shape: (3, 3)
a      b    second
str   str   struct[2]
"a"   "b"   {"b","c"}
"aa"  "bb"  {"bb","cc"}
"aaa" "bbb" {"bbb","ccc"}
```

Here I am attaching  a notebook link which is almost same case that you were looking for.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/baladevdebasisjena/otto-polars-light-jsonl-to-paraquest-conversion