# Creating Datafusion's Dataframe from Vec<Struct> in Rust?

Tags: rust, apache-arrow-datafusion

I am trying to do something similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210165/371082) but instead of using the polars library, I will like to use the [Datafusion library](https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion)

The idea is to go from a vec of struct like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Test {
    id:u32,
    amount:u32
}
```

and save to Parquet files, just like in the question I referenced.

While it was possible using polars, as seen in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210165/371082) to achieve this by going from the Struct, serialise to JSON and then build the Dataframe from that, I could not find similar approach using Datafusion.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [parquet_derive](https://crates.io/crates/parquet_derive)  is designed exactly for the usecase of writing Rust structs to/from Parquet files. DataFusion would be useful if you wanted to process the resulting data,  for example filtering or aggregating it with SQL

Here is an example in the docs: https://docs.rs/parquet_derive/30.0.1/parquet_derive/derive.ParquetRecordWriter.html

Comment: So basically use the correct tool to generate the parquet files…use data fusion to query