# Rust - polars - List[struct] to Columns and rows

Tags: rust, data-wrangling, rust-polars

I try to use polars. I'm parsing a rest-Endpoint. And now I want to transfer the data to columns and rows. So each struct key - value should be in its own Column and the key will be the header for every entry. Can someone give me a hint how that could be done?
Thank you very much.

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ fields                            │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[2]]                   │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{"colum1","valueC1_row1"}, {"column2","valueC2_row1"}], ..│
│ [{"colum1","valueC1_row2"}, {"column2","valueC2_row2"}], ..│
│ [{"colum1","valueC1_row3"}, {"column2","valueC2_row3"}], ..│
│ [{"colum1","valueC1_row4"}, {"column2","valueC2_row4"}], ..│
│ [{"colum1","valueC1_row5"}, {"column2","valueC2_row5"}], ..│
└───────────────────────────────────┘

The End result should be:
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ colum1 │ colum2 | ....            |
│ ---    | ---    |                 │
│ string | string | ....            │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
valueC1_row1|valueC2_row1
valueC1_row2|valueC2_row1
valueC1_row3|valueC2_row1
valueC1_row4|valueC2_row1
valueC1_row5|valueC2_row1
```

Comment: Can we get a sample input DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely what you asked for, but maybe another approach is more feasible:

If you deserialize the objects/records you receive from the REST endpoint first into a vector of a (possibly self-defined) Rust struct type, then converting that into a Polars DataFrame is much easier (you could use a macro for that, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167416/creating-polars-dataframe-from-vecstruct), and snippet below).

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

// Self-defined struct to deserialize REST response into
struct Record {
    field1: String,
    field2: i32,
}

// Macro to convert a vec of structs into a Polars DataFrame
macro_rules! struct_to_dataframe {
    ($input:expr, [$($field:ident),+]) => {
        {
            // Extract the field values into separate vectors
            $(let mut $field = Vec::new();)*

            for e in $input.into_iter() {
                $($field.push(e.$field);)*
            }
            df!(
                $(stringify!($field) => $field,)*
            )
        }
    };
}

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let df: DataFrame = struct_to_dataframe!(
        vec![
            Record {
                field1: "val1".into(),
                field2: 1
            },
            Record {
                field1: "val2".into(),
                field2: 2
            }
        ],
        [field1, field2]
    )?;
    println!("{:?}", df);
    // shape: (2, 2)
    // ┌────────┬────────┐
    // │ field1 ┆ field2 │
    // │ ---    ┆ ---    │
    // │ str    ┆ i32    │
    // ╞════════╪════════╡
    // │ val1   ┆ 1      │
    // │ val2   ┆ 2      │
    // └────────┴────────┘

    Ok(())
}
```